# *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:) Unable to retrieve array/collection from MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am a beginner at Express and Mongoose and for learning I am trying to retrieve an object from the MongoDB Atlas using `Mongoose.Model`. I have created the collections schema in CoursesModel.js and I am trying to retrieve it in a get request from the database using `Model.find().then()` but it returns nothing. I want to know where I am messing it up.

CourseModel.js

```
const Mongoose= require("mongoose");
const Course_schema=Mongoose.Schema;

const CourseObj=new Course_schema({
    type: {type:String, required:true},
    Uni:{type:String, required:true},
    Level:{type:String, required:true},
    Programs:{type:String, required:true},
    Availability:{type:String, required:true},
    Language:{type:String, required:true},
    Name:{type:String, required:true},
    img:{type:String, required:true}
})
const Course_Model= Mongoose.model("Courses",CourseObj);
module.exports.Course_Model=Course_Model;
```

Index.js

```
const {res}=require("express");
const expressModule=require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose= require("mongoose");
const app= expressModule(); 
app.use(expressModule.json());

const Course_Collection=require("./CourseDb");
const course_model=Course_Collection.Course_Model;


//Connection establishes successfully
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin1:12345@cluster1.hojfs.mongodb.net/Edx?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{ useUnifiedTopology: true,  useNewUrlParser: true} 
).then((res)=>{
    console.log("Database Connected"+res);
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server listening at port 3000")
})
app.get("/addCourses",(request,response)=>{
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    console.log("Get function called at server");
   course_model.find().then(
        (Courses)=>{
            console.log("List of courses:"+Courses[0]);//trying to get the first object but its undefined
            response.send(Courses);
        }
    ).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
})
```

Comment: Is there actually an error which says `*Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:) Unable to retrieve array/collection from MongoDB Atlas`? If so, where in the code causes it?

Comment: @programmerRaj in my react component where I want to get the collection after component gets mounted. On my servers console it returns undefined thats why I believe error is in my Model or somewhere in API.

Comment: I looked at https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find, and I don't think mongoose `find()` returns a promise. In the example it used `find().exec()` for a promise. Maybe you have to add a `.exec()` after the `find()`?

Comment: Well I am tried find and i guess I am heading in right direction. Btw take a look https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Answer (score 1):

well first you can try the request in postman for easy verification . to be a 100 % sure it's coming form the api . second apply this :

in  your model exports :
change :

```
        const Course_Model= Mongoose.model("Courses",CourseObj);
        module.exports.Course_Model=Course_Model;
```

to :

```
         exports.Course_Model= Mongoose.model("Courses",CourseObj);
```

in your index

```
      const {Course_Model}=require("./CourseDb");
      const express = require('express');
      const router = express.Router();

     router.get("/addCourses",async (request,response)=>{
        try{
               response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
              console.log("Get function called at server");
              const list = await Course_Model.find();
                if(list){
              response.status(200).json({ list});
                   }
           }
        catch(error){

              response.status(404).json({error});
            }
     
           })
```

let me know if it helps .